# Having issues with comparing date ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I am pulling dates from separate sheets but when using if statement the results are wrong but the dates are correct any help?

```
Dim tacholine, cal_line As Long
Dim tachodate, calstartdate, calenddate As Date


cal_line = 1
'next calender line
cal_line = cal_line + 1

For tacholine = 1 To 842
'check Week 1
tachodate = Format(Worksheets("All Workers").Range("d" & tacholine), "dd/mm/yyyy")
calstartdate = Format(Worksheets("Calender").Range("b" & cal_line), "dd/mm/yyyy")
calenddate = Format(Worksheets("Calender").Range("c" & cal_line), "dd/mm/yyyy")

If tachodate >= calstartdate And tachodate <= calenddate Then
  Application.StatusBar = "Match found : " & tachodate & " between dates " & calstartdate & " and " & calenddate
  Worksheets("All Workers").Range("u" & tacholine).Value = Worksheets("Calender").Range("A" & cal_line)
End If

Next tacholine
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are declaring multiple variables on one line, make sure each variable is specifically declared i.e.

```
Dim tachodate, calstartdate, calenddate As Date
```

should be

```
 Dim tachodate As Date, calstartdate As Date, calenddate As Date
```

In VBA, `Dim tachodate, calstartdate, calenddate As Date` means only `calenddate` is declared As Date and `tachodate, calstartdate` are treated as Variant.

May be try

```
Dim tacholine, cal_line As Long
'declare all variables separately
Dim tachodate As Date, calstartdate As Date, calenddate As Date

cal_line = 1
'next calender line
'cal_line = cal_line + 1    'moved inside loop

For tacholine = 1 To 842

cal_line = cal_line + 1
'check Week 1
tachodate = Format(Worksheets("All Workers").Range("d" & tacholine), "dd/mm/yyyy")
calstartdate = Format(Worksheets("Calender").Range("b" & cal_line), "dd/mm/yyyy")
calenddate = Format(Worksheets("Calender").Range("c" & cal_line), "dd/mm/yyyy")

If tachodate >= calstartdate And tachodate <= calenddate Then
  Application.StatusBar = "Match found : " & tachodate & " between dates " & calstartdate & " and " & calenddate
  Worksheets("All Workers").Range("u" & tacholine).Value = Worksheets("Calender").Range("A" & cal_line)
End If

Next tacholine
```

Comment: You beat me to it.  Was just going to add that `tachodate` and `calstartdate` are declared as variants and `Format` returns a string so the OP is comparing dates with strings.  And add that it's `Calendar` rather than `Calender`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - Certainly OP will read your comment and I guess its better to leave spelling correction upto him. :-)

Comment: @DataAnalyst - Take care of `Calender` also if you want as suggested by @DarrenBartrup-Cook.

Comment: @Mrig I would also throw in there that `Format(...)` is returning a string which is already being implicitly converted to a `Date`. The `Format` operation is then wasted (since a `Date` can't have a `String` format. As a result, that bit should be cut out. It is also worth noting that the code still relies on the `Activeworkbook`. There's an opportunity to improve your answer further if you can properly qualify everything.